# VB6, check if application is running on the network

Tags: vb6

I have a VB6 application that should be able to check if the same (or a certain other) application is running on other pc's in the network. The goal of this is being sure the application is not running on any pc in the network in order to do a database compress.
If the application is detected somewhere in the network, can i stop it with my vb6 app. ?

Any idea how to achieve this with vb6 ?

Thanks in advance,
Dirk

Comment: So the two instances will detect and try to kill each other?

Comment: What's the database type? Security issues makes this a really complex solution. You might want to see if you can bring your database in a `Single Connection` state.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to find all instances of a running program on all hosts on a LAN?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3190056/how-to-find-all-instances-of-a-running-program-on-all-hosts-on-a-lan)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to check if there are other application instances running](http://stackoverflow.com/q/16199858/11683)

Comment: the database is Ms Access. The check should be done if a user is stopping his VB6 application. If it's run somewhere else on the network the database compress will not be executed, else it will execute.

Comment: Suppose you check that no other apps are running and decide to compress the database. The millisecond after you've checked but before you started the compression, another app is launched. What is going to happen?

Comment: The user stops his app if he is leaving the office, so the compress will start if the last users closes his VB app.

Comment: What I'm trying to say is that the common solution to all these race condition-prone checks is to "just do it" and handle/ignore the error. You cannot compress a database that is opened by other users. So just try, and if you succeed you were the last one.

Answer (score 0):

```
Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\.\root\cimv2")

Set colItems = objWMIService.ExecQuery("Select * From Win32_Process")

For Each objItem in colItems
    msgbox objItem.ProcessID & " " & objItem.CommandLine
    If objItem.name = "Calculator.exe" then objItem.terminate
Next
```

The dot in `\\.\` above is the computer name. `.` means local computer but you can put another computer's name in there instead. To see what properties/methods are available type in a command prompt

```
wmic process get /?
```

and

```
 wmic process call /?
```